# How do I split split from specific character to specific character

Tags: python-3.x, regex, sorting, arraylist, split

I have a file.txt with urls such as:

asd.com/abc.xyz?b=21

asd.com/abc.xyz?a=1&c=2

asd.com/abc.xyz?a=12&d=21

asd.com/abc.xy?b=21

asd.com/abc.xy?a=1&c=2

asd.com/abc.xy?a=12&d=21

I need a result like:

asd.com/abc.xyz?a=*&b=*&c=*&d=*

asd.com/abc.xy?a=*&b=*&c=*&d=*

As it can be seen i want each parameter of specific url to be linked to only one.

I have written a code to seperate by ? and remove everything after ? and then removed the duplicate but my code completely removes the a, b, c and d from the urls

```js
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
actualout = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in open("txt", "r"):
    line = line.split("?", 1)[0]
    outfile.write(line+"\n")
outfile.close()

for line in open("out.txt", "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        actualout.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)

actualout.close()
```

Comment: When you have two values for one parameter, as in `"asd.com/abc.xyz?a=1&c=2", 
"asd.com/abc.xyz?a=12&d=21"`, how do you decide which value to keep? Do you want `a=1` or `a=12`?

Comment: I actually would replace all values with a wild card to match better, or use only first value, different parameters in specific url is what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

- Split on `?`
- Group by first part of the url
- Concatenate all second parts of the url for the same group

Sidenote: I strongly advise you to use `with` contexts to encapsulate calls to `open()`.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('txt', 'r'), open('output.txt', 'w') as in_file, out_file:
    for bareurl,g in groupby((line.split('?') for line in sorted(in_file)), itemgetter(0)):
        out_file.write( ''.join([bareurl,
                                 '?',
                                 '&'.join(spliturl[1] for spliturl in g),
                                 '\n'])
                      )

# OUTPUT:
# asd.com/abc.xy?a=1&c=2&a=12&d=21&b=21
# asd.com/abc.xyz?a=1&c=2&a=12&d=21&b=21
```

If you want to keep only the last value of each parameter, to avoid supplying more than one value per parameter in a url, you could build a dict mapping parameters to their values:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('txt', 'r'), open('output.txt', 'w') as in_file, out_file:
    for bareurl,g in groupby((line.split('?') for line in sorted(in_file)), key=itemgetter(0)):
        d = dict(e.split('=') for spliturl in g for e in spliturl[1].split('&'))
        out_file.write( ''.join([bareurl,
                                 '?',
                                 '&'.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in d),
                                 '\n'])
                      )

# OUTPUT:
# asd.com/abc.xy?a=12&c=2&d=21&b=21
# asd.com/abc.xyz?a=12&c=2&d=21&b=21
```